# pipenv: Pipfile.lock file shows different version than whats installed

Tags: python, django, pipenv

I have django installed using `pipenv install django`

I check the version of Django installed using

```
python -m django --version
3.0.3
```

So its `3.0.3`

I have done `pipenv lock` later sometime after installing few more packages

I check the Pipfile.lock to see what `django` version it locks to `3.0.6`

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "1c89f4b79e61ac01a5f1b50db6b6b0b4ba34199a99f96caf61885884b43a8b3a"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {
            "python_version": "3.7"
        },
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "pypi",
                "url": "https://pypi.org/simple",
                "verify_ssl": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "default": {
    ....
        "django": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:051ba55d42daa3eeda3944a8e4df2bc96d4c62f94316dea217248a22563c3621",
                "sha256:9aaa6a09678e1b8f0d98a948c56482eac3e3dd2ddbfb8de70a868135ef3b5e01"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==3.0.6"
        },
    ....
    }
    "develop": {
        ....
        "django": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:051ba55d42daa3eeda3944a8e4df2bc96d4c62f94316dea217248a22563c3621",
                "sha256:9aaa6a09678e1b8f0d98a948c56482eac3e3dd2ddbfb8de70a868135ef3b5e01"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==3.0.6"
        },
    ....
    }
```

And this is my `Pipfile`

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
django-extensions = "*"
ipython = "*"
werkzeug = "*"
pydotplus = "*"
django-querycount = "*"
jupyter = "*"
flower = "*"
django-request-logging = "*"

[packages]
django = "*"
psycopg2 = "*"
django-environ = "*"
celery = "*"
redis = "==3.3.11"
pyjwt = "*"
django-webpack-loader = "*"
django-rest-framework = "*"
kombu = "*"
django-otp = "*"
pyotp = "*"
gunicorn = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

Also i checked the version from `pipenv graph` it shows the right installed version `3.0.3`

```
django-environ==0.4.5
django-extensions==2.2.6
  - six [required: >=1.2, installed: 1.14.0]
django-otp==0.9.0
  - django [required: >=1.11, installed: 3.0.3]
    - asgiref [required: ~=3.2, installed: 3.2.7]
    - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2019.3]
    - sqlparse [required: >=0.2.2, installed: 0.3.0]
django-querycount==0.7.0
django-request-logging==0.7.0
  - Django [required: Any, installed: 3.0.3]
    - asgiref [required: ~=3.2, installed: 3.2.7]
    - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2019.3]
    - sqlparse [required: >=0.2.2, installed: 0.3.0]
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
  - djangorestframework [required: Any, installed: 3.11.0]
    - django [required: >=1.11, installed: 3.0.3]
      - asgiref [required: ~=3.2, installed: 3.2.7]
      - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2019.3]
      - sqlparse [required: >=0.2.2, installed: 0.3.0]
django-webpack-loader==0.7.0
```

So how to understand the `3.0.6` in Pipfile.lock. When i am trying to create a new virtual env using this file will my django version change from `3.0.3` to `3.0.6`

Ofcourse here it may not matter. But i am afraid if version changes from `3.0.3` to `3.2.0` (its major change then)

Comment: You need to set the version explicitly in the Pipfile, otherwise it will just keep installing newer versions.

Comment: Are you sure. So Pipfile.lock does not check the installed version. I understand when we run `pipenv update` then it can install the latest versions. But with a running setup of environment we want the `Pipfile.lock` to take care of the versions which are used in the `running setup `

Comment: Pipenv.lock is created based on your Pipfile, not what packages you have installed. In other words, it's **not** like running `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. I used this script to change the `"*"`s in your `Pipfile` to the actual versions in the `Pipfile.lock` file, as I needed specific versions.

```
import os
import json

# Globals
STAR = '"*"'
PIPFILE = "Pipfile"
PIPFILE_T = "Pipfile_temp"
PIPFILE_LOCK = "Pipfile.lock"

def main():
    """Entry point"""

    # Get entire Pipfile.lock file
    with open(PIPFILE_LOCK) as pipfile_lock:
        pf = json.load(pipfile_lock)

    # Get the packages
    pkgs = pf.get("default")
    pkgs_dev = pf.get("develop")
    
    # Unify them as a source
    source = {**pkgs, **pkgs_dev}

    # Parse the PipFile
    with open(PIPFILE) as pipfile:
        with open(PIPFILE_T, 'w+') as new_pip_file:
            
            # Iterate each line
            for line in pipfile:
                line = line.strip()

                # Check for stars
                if STAR in line:
                    # Get package name
                    pkg = line.split("=")
                    pkg = pkg[0].strip()

                    # Get affiliated version
                    pkg_ = source.get(pkg)
                    vsn_ = pkg_.get("version")

                    # Replace it with the version
                    tw = line.replace(STAR, f'"{vsn_}"')
                
                # Skip others
                else:
                    tw = line
                
                # Update the temp Pipfile
                new_pip_file.write(f"{tw}\n")

    # Remove old and rename temp
    os.remove(PIPFILE)
    os.rename(PIPFILE_T, PIPFILE)

main() if __name__ == "__main__" else None
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/olumidesan/9227c20d9d6fd88167915789eb35ac34)